# Angular 8 Universal ssr, window in third party library

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I added universal to my angular application using [@ng-toolkit/universal](https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/blob/master/schematics/universal/README.md)
after building and while running the server I had this error is: 
`var matches = window.Element.prototype.matches;ReferenceError: window is not defined`
this piece of code is in a third party library that uses the window object that doesn't work in the server.
I tried to define it as a global variable in the server.ts file like this

```
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '.', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
```

and i tried to only use the library in the browser like this

```
  constructor(
            @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object,
        ) {
            this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
        }
        ngOnInit() {
            if (this.isBrowser) {//do stuff}
}
```

but the error persists. Is there a way to define the window object so it can be used in the server or how to ignore the library when doing SSR

Comment: Do you have exactly the same error after using domino?

Comment: @David , it was just one javaScript library that doesn't work with universal i just had to replace it.